# I can't use 'predict' method when assigning my trained svc model to the user input in flask

Tags: flask

I can't use 'predict' method when assigning my trained svc model to the user input in flask. it gives me this error, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'"
I used python to develop my model and used visual studio code.

**This is my app.py code.**

```
    app = Flask(__name__)


model = pickle.load(open('hsd.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/submit", methods =['POSt'])
def submit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text1 = request.form['tweet']
        probb = [np.array(text1)]
        y = model.predict(probb)
  
        return render_template("submit.html", n = y)

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**This is my html code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hate speech Detection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hate speech Detection</h1>
    <h3>Enter your tweet</h3>

    <form action="/submit" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name='tweet' placeholder="input your tweet">
    <input type="submit" value="predict">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my submit html code.**

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>

        <h1>  PREDICTION :  </h1>
    
    {%if n == 0%}
    <h1>No hp</h1>  
   

    {%else%}
    <h1>hp</h1>
   
    
    {%endif%}

        <br><br>
    <a href='/'>go back to home page</a>

    </center>
</body>
</html>`
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\deploy\app.py", line 53, in submit
    y = model.predict(text1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include your full traceback error.  What is the value of ```pickle.load(open('hsd.pkl', 'rb'))```?

Comment: @ewong it's a twitter hate speech detection model. i have trained it by giving twitter data set. I have updated my question with traceback error. Thank you